# Calling multiple functions with onchange

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, onchange

All this is a little bit over my experience but I have looked everywhere I could, and researched this stuff for 6 hours so far today and am just running into brick walls.

I have a table, where a user enters two variables and from those two variables 12 different numbers are spit out.
The problem those numbers are spit out as plain text strings into readonly text fields, and I need them to be displayed as (US) currency.
All of the input fields in the table are using onchange to run the first function which does the calculations, but the second and third functions which I found online I can not get to run.

HTML:

```
 <form name="form" >

<table width="550" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="265" height="30"><div align="right">Number of Business Customers</div></td>
</tr>
<TR>
<td width="265" height="30"><div align="right">Number of Business Clients:</div></td>
<td width="142" div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;" name="sum1" onChange="updatesum();CurrencyFormatted();CommaFormatted90;" /></td>
<td width="129" div align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<TR>
<td height="30"><div align="right">Average Number of Employees:</td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;" name="sum2" onChange="updatesum();CurrencyFormatted();CommaFormatted();" /></TD>
<TD div align="center">&nbsp;</TD>
<TR>
<td height="30"><div align="right">Anticipated Employee Tax Reduction:</div></td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none;" name="sum16"  readonly "></TD>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum26" readonly><BR /></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<td height="30"><div align="right">Potential Payroll Tax Reduction (annually):</div></td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum17" readonly ></TD>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum27" readonly ></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<td height="30"><div align="right">Potential Payroll Tax Reduction (monthly):</td>
<TD div align="center"><input type="text" style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum18" readonly ></td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum28" readonly ></td>
</TR>
<TR>
<td height="30"><div align="right">Pearl Logic Billing (50% of savings, for 12 months):</td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum19" readonly ></td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum29" readonly ></td>
</TR>
<TR>
<td height="30"><div align="right">Sales Agent Monthly Comp (8%):</td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum14" readonly ></td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum24" readonly ></td>
</TR>
<TR>
<td height="30"><div align="right">Sales Agent Total Comp (8%):</td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum15" readonly ></td>
<TD div align="center"><input style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;border:none" name="sum25" readonly ></td>
</TR>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function updatesum() {




document.form.sum14.value = ((((((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*300))/12)/2)*.08);
document.form.sum24.value = ((((((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*400))/12)/2)*.08);
document.form.sum15.value = (((((((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*300))/12)/2)*.08)*12);
document.form.sum25.value = (((((((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*400))/12)/2)*.08)*12);
document.form.sum16.value = 300;
document.form.sum26.value = 400;
document.form.sum17.value = ((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*300);
document.form.sum27.value = ((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*400);
document.form.sum18.value = (((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*300)/12);
document.form.sum28.value = (((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*400)/12);
document.form.sum19.value = ((((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*300)/12)/2);
document.form.sum29.value = ((((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*400)/12)/2);
}


//--></script>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function CurrencyFormatted()
{
    var i = parseFloat(amount);
    if(isNaN(i)) { i = 0.00; }
    var minus = '';
    if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    i = parseInt((i + .005) * 100);
    i = i / 100;
    s = new String(i);
    if(s.indexOf('.') < 0) { s += '.00'; }
    if(s.indexOf('.') == (s.length - 2)) { s += '0'; }
    s = minus + s;
    return s;
}
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function CommaFormatted()
{
    var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
    var a = amount.split('.',2)
    var d = a[1];
    var i = parseInt(a[0]);
    if(isNaN(i)) { return ''; }
    var minus = '';
    if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    var n = new String(i);
    var a = [];
    while(n.length > 3)
    {
        var nn = n.substr(n.length-3);
        a.unshift(nn);
        n = n.substr(0,n.length-3);
    }
    if(n.length > 0) { a.unshift(n); }
    n = a.join(delimiter);
    if(d.length < 1) { amount = n; }
    else { amount = n + '.' + d; }
    amount = minus + amount;
    return amount;
}

//--></script>
```

Comment: **java is not javascript**. Where does `amount` come from in your functions?

Comment: If you open up your browsers JavaScript console (most browsers have one), do you see any errors?

Comment: My apologies. If you are referring to "amount" as referred to in the fuctions "CommaFormatted()" and "CurrencyFormatted()", I have NO idea where amount comes from in those.
I only created the first function "updatesum()" and the HTML portion. I only grabbed those last two functions in an attempt to get the results from "updatesum()" to return into the HTML as currency instead of a string.

Comment: So I could give you some random code and you would run it without even trying to understand it, sweet. I have this **amazing** script you just have to try...

Comment: @bmorris591 , I would LOVE to understand the code you gave me. In fact this morning I had no idea how to even call a function in HTML and now I do know how to do that because I found some script and broke it apart until I understood how it worked. I am asking for help with something that I have a deadline on because my boss does not want to hire someone to do website work since I know "a little" about the stuff. I am not likely to learn this from the ground up within the next few hours and so I thought to seek help, and learn from that. I am using CodeAcademy to try and learn this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions have an undefined `amount` variable. Presumably they just crash with an error.

First you need to remove those function calls from the `onChange` listener.

Second, change the functions to take an unformatted value and return a formatted one

```
function CurrencyFormatted(amount) { //<-- notice the method parameter
    var i = parseFloat(amount);
    if(isNaN(i)) { i = 0.00; }
    var minus = '';
    if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    i = parseInt((i + .005) * 100);
    i = i / 100;
    s = new String(i);
    if(s.indexOf('.') < 0) { s += '.00'; }
    if(s.indexOf('.') == (s.length - 2)) { s += '0'; }
    s = minus + s;
    return s;
}
```

Now change each of your set calls in your `updatesum` to first format the value

```
var sum14 = ((((((document.form.sum1.value -0)*(document.form.sum2.value -0)*300))/12)/2)*.08);
var formattedSum14 = CommaFormatted(CurrencyFormatted(sum14));
document.form.sum14.value = sum14;
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean about undefined variable. Additionally, I will update the set calls, that makes sense. But how do I remove the functions from the onChange listener?

Comment: Change `onChange="updatesum();CurrencyFormatted();CommaFormatted();"` to just `onChange="updatesum()"`. You don't need to call these functions from `onChange` - you use them in `updatesum` as utility functions.